# Why is necessary to consider threshold value of 30 to predict type of distribtuion in Statistics?

Tags: statistics

In most Statistics book, it is given that if the sample size is less than 30, it follows t-distribution.Why is sample size less than 30 is considered as standard for estimating distribution?

Comment: Cf the *rules of thumb* when (in terms of $n$ and $p$) using normal distribution instead of exact binomial distribution is appropriate

Comment: $T = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{s/\sqrt{n}}$, where $\bar X$ and $s$ are sample mean and SD of a normal sample of size $n$, has Student's t distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom _regardless_ of the sample size $n  \ge 2.$ // When $n$ exceeds about 30, $T$ is _approximately_ normal for testing at 5% level or making 95% confidence intervals. // When $\sigma$ is known, use z tests and CIs; when $\sigma$ is unknown and estimated by $s,$ then _always_ use t tests and t CIs. Sample size has _nothing_ to do with the choice of z or t methods. Estimation and testing give better results as $n$ increases.